# Best practice for shut down and restart of Replicated SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 in production. We have transactional and snapshot replication implemented in our environment and unfortunately the subscribers are also the distributors. Now, after almost 5 years we have to shut down all the servers for maintenance (power outage) and then restart them when the maintenance is done. I know this is not ideal but this is how it is going to be done.

My only concern is that is there any sequence of steps recommended while restarting the replicated servers? I mean something like Publisher should be shut down before the Subscriber etc. TIA